# Intelij Spring Boot 2 application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Idea

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.4 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-191.8026.42, built on July 30, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.6

I'm trying to follow a Udemy course on Spring Boot 2 and copying step by step what the instructor is doing. The instructor is using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition though.

When the instructor goes to edit any of the Spring Boot application.properties, IntelliJ code completion kicks in and you can see all the options/intelligence at work in the IDE. I don't see this at all. I am pretty much certain that I have enabled everything I can. The application.properties DO works fine. The changes I make there work fine in my Spring project, such as logging or port selection and more; it's just that there is no IntelliJ code completion in the iDE.

Code completion is working fine in my Java classes, its just the application.properties (which is located, as per default, in the Resources dir in my project ).

Is this feature only available in the Ultimate edition? Should this work in the community edition? And if so, I'd really appreciate some pointers as to how to enable it.

Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered. Better get myself over to the Jetbrains shop then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, community edition of IntellIJ doesn't support spring boot features. You'll need enterprise edition to use all these features.

You still can run the spring boot application though only because it has a main method (assuming you're working with Jars)

Answer (score 1):

The code auto-completion feature for *application.properties* file and other Spring Boot framework related features are only available in **Ultimate** edition, and **not** in Community edition. That's why you won't see code auto-completion or suggestion features.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build JavaEE apps (comprising, then, Spring app), you need to buy the Ultimate version of IntelliJ. Look at this: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows